# Blank page after trying to login in a form using PDO

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to create a simple script for login in php using PDO and a PostgreSql database. I have created the database in Postgre and these scripts. The first script is called cbconnection.php:

```html
<?php session_start(); $conn=pg_connect( "dbname=gestionelavori  user=gestionelavori password=gestionelavori port=5432 "); $stat=pg_connection_status($conn); if ($stat===P GSQL_CONNECTION_OK) { echo 'Connection status ok'; } else { echo
'Connection status bad'; } include_once 'utente.php'; $utente=new Utente($conn); ?>
```

The other script is utente.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>Sistema di Gestione Rapporti Lavoro
</title>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_utente" placeholder="Username or E mail ID" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="btn-login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;SIGN IN
      </button>
    </div>


  </form>

  <?php include_once 'dbconnection.php'; class Utente{ private $db; function __construct($conn) { $this->db = $conn; } public function login($nome_utente,$password) { try { $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM utente WHERE nome_utente=nome_utente "); $stmt->execute(array('nome_utente'=>$nome_utente)); $utenteRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if($stmt->rowCount()
  > 0) { if($password, $utenteRow['password']) { $_SESSION['utente_session'] = $utenteRow['id_utente']; return true; } else { return false; } } } catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } } public function is_loggedin() { if(isset($_SESSION['utente_session']))
  { return true; } } } ?>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that I can't see anything in my page. Is there any error I have made or something I should fix? I'm new at PDO. Thanks!

Comment: No my code is pg_connect

Comment: `if ($stat===P GSQL_CONNECTION_OK) {` This whitespace should not be here